# javascript dom using futures

Tags: javascript, dom, future

the [dom standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#futures) now apparently includes `futures`

from what I can tell from the doc, this seems to be a different flavor that what most people advertise as `futures` - in particular there seems to be no `join` function which is at the heart of other `futures` doc I have read.

what's the deal?

are there any standard examples on the approach that the dom is using?

is this approach actually coming to life in actual javascript?